# scan and connect to wifi from linux terminal on virtual machine

Tags: linux, osx

I am trying to scan wifi networks via Linux terminal running on a virtual machine. I am running virtual machine on Mac OS. On MAC terminal, I can see all Wi-Fi networks using (airport) command and can connect to one network.

The NetworkAdapter setting for Virtual machine is set to "Share with MAC".

On Linux terminal, When I do `ifconfig -a`, I get

`eth0` & `lo`

However, when I type : `sudo iwlist eth0 scan` , I get error message:

```
sudo iwlist eth0 scan
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

Can someone explain how I can do that with Linux running on virtual machine? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error message? I believe you wanted to mention the error message but mentioned the command again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is to assume that whatever software you're using to run the virtual machine will pass the WiFi extension through to your VM.

If you ran

```
lspci
```

in the terminal of your VM you'd most likely find that it sees an
Intel, Realtek or AMD **wired** adapter.

Comment: I am newbie to linux. yes i got a VMware SVGA II Adapter answer. How should I resolve this issue plz

Comment: There's nothing to be resolved.  Short of finding a virtualisation platform that passes the physical hardware through to your VM there's no way you will be able to use the wifi adapter of the host as such from within a VM.  In short **it can't be done**.

Comment: what is the best way then ? As I will run a C program from my virtual machine to scan and connect a specific wifi network?

Comment: Again: this will not work. I don't know how to spell it out more clearly. Make your C program work on the host.  The VM doesn't (can't, will never, ... ) see the wifi adapter, so any efforts you put into this - including posting questions about it - are wasted.

Comment: don't get aggressive. was just asking other way !! that's it

Comment: what if I used some wirless device such as Dongle . . I was reading somewhere that it may be possible. Will be waiting for ur kind reply.

Comment: I wasn't being aggressive at all.  If you have a USB wifi device that VMware can pass through to the linux VM that should work; but I don't know VMware on the Mac at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Alfa USB long-range adapter. When you plug it in to USB, it will ask who gets control?  host or vm? give access to the vm.

voila: "iwlist wlan0 scan | less" will show what you are looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).